# Query data from mongoose and display it on a html page

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb

This is my schema

```
var productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    description: String
});
var Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

In my index.js i am using

```
exports.welcome = function(req,res) {
    Product.find({},{},function(err,docs) {
        res.render('welcome', {
            "productlist" : docs
        });
    });
};
```

In my app.js i am calling this statement where routes is my variable to call welcome in index.js
    app.get('/welcome',routes.welcome);

My schema is also written in index.js. What i want to do is display all the products with their name and description in my html page named "welcome.html".

Can anyone tell me like what should i write in my html page to do this.

Comment: what html renderer are you using?

Comment: app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');  This is what i have written in my app.js.

Comment: Everywhere i can find like sending data to jade and then display in jade but not in html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your latest comment, it means you are using [EmbeddedJS](http://embeddedjs.com/) as templating engine. Your answer is well documented [here](http://code.google.com/p/embeddedjavascript/w/list).

For complicity, an example of `welcome.html` to display results is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Products</title>
</head>

<body>
<ul>
<% for(var i=0; i<productlist.length; i++) {%>
   <li><%= productlist[i].name %> : <%= productlist[i].description %></li>
<% } %>
</ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you help me on one more thing.I want to send data from html page to mongoose. I have done this thing by creating a form using a post request and I am able to send the data to mongoose but what if I do not want to use a form can i still send the data ? If you have an example plz share the link.

Comment: You can send the data from client to server using AJAX https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29 . For more information search the internet or ask a separate question.